# Why are Switching Signals Used for DC-AC converter

Tags: rectifier, 555, dc-ac

I have noticed that oftentimes an NE555 timer circuit is used to generate AC switching signals, which allow a DC to AC rectifier to convert a DC voltage to AC voltage. This AC voltage can be used for electromagnetic induction. Why isn't a signal from the NE555 timer used instead for induction? Why can we not treat the NE555 timer as a DC to AC converter? What makes the Ne555 timer + DC to AC converter better?

Here is a related picture (although it doesn't use a NE555 timer, but something else to create switching signals). The switching signals are AC so why bother using a DC to AC converter for induction when we have the switching signals?
[image]

Comment: Please provide a reference as what you suggest doesn’t line up with what I’ve observed. An inverter using a 555 is at the low end of town methinks and doesn’t translate to ‘better’.

Comment: @Kartman I added a reference picture

Comment: The transistors are required for current gain - the signals from the 555 or 4047 are not ‘strong’ enough to power thé transformer.

Comment: Generally, one would protect the oscillator from transient voltage spikes when driving an inductive load. The BD699 is good up to 80V, which is comfortably higher than twice the supply voltage (2x12=24V). Max input for 555 is 15V. And then there's the difference between 8A and 200mA drive current.